Where can I see gitlab group importing status?
I use direct transfer to migrate my group. The group has around 20 projects so it takes a while. I closed the importing status page then I can't find the page anymore even if I use root account to log in.
Where can I find importing status page? When import finishes will I get any notification ?I can't find these information from the gitlab document.

GitLab typically sends email notifications to the user who initiated the import when the process completes, assuming your email settings allow for it.

I finally find that in a "hidden" place. I have to click Import group button again,  Groups -> New group -> Import group. Then click "history" to see the import status,
I see some error "BulkImports::Pipeline::ExpiredError -- Empty export status on source instance". I can't find clear explanation for that. But it seems not a serious error.

